# rails db:migrate をすると「Mysql2::Error: The user specified as a definer」というエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

`rails db:migrate` を実行すると以下のエラーが発生します。

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/yuzuki/environment/yuzuki_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

以下はdatabase.ymlです

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: Yuzuki_1201
  host: localhost
  
development:
  <<: *default
  database: yuzuki_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: yuzuki_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: yuzuki_app_production
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

以下言語のバージョンです。

・Ruby (3.0.1)
・Ruby on Rails (6.1.3.2)
・MySQL (8.0.25)

このエラーの原因と解決策を教えてくださると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117262/3240599 この内容は試してみましたか？

Comment: `mysql -u root -p
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1;
mysql_upgrade -u root -p`
を実行しましたが、３行目で次のエラーが発生しました。
`The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.`
日本語翻訳してみましたが、古いディレクトリ、mysqlバイナリがわからず解決に至りませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。最近MySQLをアップデートしたことはありますか？どうやらこのエラーはバージョン間の違いによるものらしいです。

Comment: railsにmysqlを接続する初期設定をしている状況で、現在のmysqlはバージョン8.0.25です。インストールした時は8.0.24だったかもしれませんが、アップデートしたか覚えていません。

Comment: うーん、そうなると私にはわかりかねます。いっそのことデータベースを作り直すのが手っ取り早いでしょうか…

Comment: 作り直すことにします。ありがとうございました。